# Load all UIViewController when application is launched

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, load, storyboard, tabbarcontroller

I have an application with a Tab Bar Controller and a lot of UIViewController, I defined the  interface on storyboard, I want that when the user lunch the application (When application loaded) all ControllerViews are loaded, and not when the user select a tab (My UIViewController are complex and it take little time to load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you posted is incorrect; You should not call `-loadView` manually. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView):

> **Discussion**
>
> You should never call this method directly. The view
>   controller calls this method when its view property is requested but
>   is currently nil. This method loads or creates a view and assigns it
>   to the view property.

So you should instead simply access the `view` property. Your modified code would then be:

```
UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    [[tabBar.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:i] view];
}
```

Also note that this work should probably not take place inside your `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, because iOS will terminate your app if this method does not return in 5 seconds. You can schedule this task on the next runloop iteration like this:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [self preloadTabs];
}];
```

Comment: Thanks it work well, I moved codes from viewDidAppear to viewDidLoad